# Is there a better way to implement HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, List<Details>>>>?

Tags: java

I need to create json response in the following format:

```
{"responseCode":"00",
"responseMessage":"Success",
"planList":[
    {"category":"category1",
    "details":...}
    {"category":"category2",
    "details":...}
    {"category":"category3",
    "details":...}
    ]}
```

I came up with `HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, List<Details>>>>`, but I feel there should be a better way to do this. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create your own class and encapsulate complex data structures. Having a map of lists of maps of list is not a good idea. Begin with `HashMap<String, Response>` where `Response` is your own class that wraps the list what has a hashmap (which can be separated to two classes as well).

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to create classes with needed fields. For example:

```
class MyResponse {
   private String responseCode;
   private String responseMessage;
   private List<Category> categories;
}

class Category {
   private String category;
   private String details;
}
```

It will increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could write classes for the different entities in your list.

For example a class Response:

```
class Response {

     private String responseCode;
     private String responseMessage;

     private List<Category> categories;
//....
}
```

and a class Category:

```
class Category {

    private String categoryName;
    private List<Details> 
    //...
}
```

This should work with different json-libraries like Gson or Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate classes for each model element and than collect full response from those clases, e.g.

```
class Category {...}

...

another classes staff

...

class Response {...}
```

where Response - final response class;